# Wordpress API V2 does not embed items when query parameter is passed

Tags: wordpress, api

Per the documentation:

> Optionally, some linked resources may be included in the response to
>   reduce the number of HTTP requests required. These resources are
>   “embedded” into the main response.
>
> Embedding is triggered by setting the _embed query parameter on the
>   request. This will then include embedded resources under the _embedded
>   key adjacent to the _links key. The layout of this object mirrors the
>   _links object, but includes the embedded resource in place of the link 
>   properties.

Despite this, when I make the following GET request:

http://anawins.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/2986?_embed

The resulting JSON is identical the request without `?_embed`.

With embed:

```
{
    "id": 2986,
    "date": "2016-05-09T03:00:42",
    "date_gmt": "2016-05-09T07:00:42",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/?p=2986"
    },
    "modified": "2016-05-08T16:37:39",
    "modified_gmt": "2016-05-08T20:37:39",
    "slug": "the-secret-to-speaking-with-more-grace",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/the-secret-to-speaking-with-more-grace\/",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "The Secret to Speaking With Grace"
    },
    "content": {
        "rendered": "<p><img class=\"aligncenter size-large wp-image-3474\" src=\"http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/the-secret-to-speaking-with-grace-367x550.png\" alt=\"Do you...."
    },
    "excerpt": {
        "rendered": "<p>I have a little..."
    },
    "author": 2,
    "featured_media": 0,
    "comment_status": "open",
    "ping_status": "open",
    "sticky": false,
    "format": "standard",
    "categories": [193, 58],
    "tags": [110, 194, 206, 205, 204],
    "better_featured_image": null,
    "_links": {
        "self": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/2986"
        }],
        "collection": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts"
        }],
        "about": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/types\/post"
        }],
        "author": [{
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/users\/2"
        }],
        "replies": [{
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/comments?post=2986"
        }],
        "version-history": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/2986\/revisions"
        }],
        "wp:attachment": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media?parent=2986"
        }],
        "wp:term": [{
            "taxonomy": "category",
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories?post=2986"
        }, {
            "taxonomy": "post_tag",
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/tags?post=2986"
        }],
        "curies": [{
            "name": "wp",
            "href": "https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}",
            "templated": true
        }]
    }
}
```

Without _embed:

```
{
    "id": 2986,
    "date": "2016-05-09T03:00:42",
    "date_gmt": "2016-05-09T07:00:42",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/?p=2986"
    },
    "modified": "2016-05-08T16:37:39",
    "modified_gmt": "2016-05-08T20:37:39",
    "slug": "the-secret-to-speaking-with-more-grace",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/the-secret-to-speaking-with-more-grace\/",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "The Secret to Speaking With Grace"
    },
    "content": {
        "rendered": "<p><img class=\"aligncenter size-large wp-image-3474\" src=\"http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/05\/the-secret-to-speaking-with-grace-367x550.png\" alt=\"Do you struggle..."
    },
    "excerpt": {
        "rendered": "<p>I have a little..."
    },
    "author": 2,
    "featured_media": 0,
    "comment_status": "open",
    "ping_status": "open",
    "sticky": false,
    "format": "standard",
    "categories": [193, 58],
    "tags": [110, 194, 206, 205, 204],
    "better_featured_image": null,
    "_links": {
        "self": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/2986"
        }],
        "collection": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts"
        }],
        "about": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/types\/post"
        }],
        "author": [{
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/users\/2"
        }],
        "replies": [{
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/comments?post=2986"
        }],
        "version-history": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/2986\/revisions"
        }],
        "wp:attachment": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media?parent=2986"
        }],
        "wp:term": [{
            "taxonomy": "category",
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories?post=2986"
        }, {
            "taxonomy": "post_tag",
            "embeddable": true,
            "href": "http:\/\/anawins.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/tags?post=2986"
        }],
        "curies": [{
            "name": "wp",
            "href": "https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}",
            "templated": true
        }]
    }
}
```

How do I change the query to make this work?

Comment: I think you must update API resource.

Comment: What's exactly beta version of your Rest API?

Comment: Version 2.0-beta13.1